# Flex TitleWindow (or NativeWindow) skinned as a Fancybox?

Tags: apache-flex, fancybox

The customer I am  working for wants to display popup in an AIR application (designed in Flex 4).I will therefore use TitleWindow and PopupManager for this (or NativeWindow could be an option too).
Pretty basic, I can handle this.

Trouble is, this customer would like this popup to be looking as a [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/), that is, with the close button, slightly out of the popup.

Do you know how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy enough.  Just create a custom skin based for your TitleWindow which you can then change the appearance and location of the close button (among other things).  The setup is fairly straightforward, but you should look up [how to skin in Flex 4](http://www.unitedmindset.com/jonbcampos/2009/07/02/flex-4-spark-skinning/).